# iOS 7 embedded calendar api

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, calendar, ios7.1

I'm fairly new to iOS development, I've been asked to write an application that moves around days in a calendar. The graphics designers thought it would be a good idea to have an embedded scrollable calendar so the user could navigate easily through dates.

I'd love to post an image for what I want but I don't have the reputation yet to do so.

This calendar view looks just like the native calendar app on iOS 7 but it's just a sideways scrollable choosing date of the month you're in and it only take a small portion of the screen. Would anybody know if there's a framework I could use to achieve similar results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: upload the image somewhere, post the link. someone will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's a little late, but I'll just post it here in case other people has the same problem.

A few months back, I had the exact same problem.
I couldn't find exactly what I need, so I had to implement it myself with UICollectionView
Anyway, after finishing my project, I've decided to make a library based on it.
This should be easier to use than any other calendar library.

https://github.com/nopshusang/SACalendar

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i think your didSelectDate:… should return a nsdate, not simple ints.

Comment: This was not late at all, thank you very much for replying I've been also doing my own views but yours is great and will help me a lot to make mine even better. It really helped!

Comment: @Nop Shusang. How can we customize this library to preselect dates of our interest, like events?

Answer (score 2):

There will most likely not be a component that does exactly what you want. A good thing to do in a situation like this is search on Github and filter by language, then sort by popularity.

Here is an example search to get you started, for "calendar":

https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&o=desc&q=calendar&ref=cmdform&s=stars&type=Repositories

A few promising candidates from that search:

https://github.com/leverdeterre/CalendarIOS7

https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar

https://github.com/square/objc-TimesSquare

https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar

https://github.com/min/MNCalendarView

There are tons of these, all slightly different, so you'll need to do some digging to find one that is most similar to what you want to accomplish.

In general, any implementation you find or create yourself should probably use a `UICollectionView` to accomplish this.

Comment: Great links!Thank you.